# Cell label not appearing for pasted image

Tags: notebooks, options, labeling, cells

When I paste an image into a notebook the cell has no label. In the Generalized Input Tutorial:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html#52003380

they show pasted images which have labels. Why are my pasted images without labels? The other cells in my notebook have labels and I have `ShowCellLabels` turned on.

Comment: the images do not have labels. click on one and save it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellLabelAutoDelete.html#20586872), you should set `CellLabelAutoDelete -> False` for making cell labels permanent:

> Create a notebook with
>   the setting `CellLabelAutoDelete -> False`:
>
> ```
> nb = CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell[Defer[1 + 1], "Input"], 
>    ExpressionCell[Defer[2 + 2], "Input"]}, CellLabelAutoDelete -> False]
> ```
>
> When inputs are evaluated, cell labels are attached to the input and
>   output cells:
>
> ```
> SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook]; SelectionEvaluate[nb]
> ```
>
> Because `CellLabelAutoDelete` is turned off, editing an input does not
>   reset its cell label. Neither does saving and reopening the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

"In/Out" labels are created, roughly, when you evaluate/create cells. And according to `CellLabelAutoDelete` documentation:

> If you edit a previously evaluated input cell, its cell label is cleared

That's what is happening when you paste copied image. A default cell is created, with a label, but then the cell is edited by pasting your image. This clears the label.

Examples from the link you've provided are consistent with this. Every cell was evaluated after pasting images, that's why those labels appeared again.